# How to modify body of a node

Tags: nodes, hooks

I have to add some data to body of my content type, how do I add it in hook_node_save. I tried adding it like shown below but it's not getting saved.

```
function mymodule_node_save($node) {
$node->body = 'test string';
}
```

Also when I do `dsm($node)` in the above function, the `$node->body` doesn't contain the string I added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such hook as `hook_node_save()`, you're probably looking for [`hook_node_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7)

> Act on a node being inserted or updated.

Also, the nody body is a field so you have to treat it as such when assigning values:

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  $node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'test string';
}
```